# i want to draw a rectangle on an image in angular2

Tags: angular, html5-canvas

I have an image i am getting from a url. I would like to draw a rectangle on this image. I'm currently trying to use canvas to achieve this but i'm not fully understanding how to implement it. When i use this code there is no change in the canvas, it remains blank.

I have this in my html

```
 <canvas #layout></canvas>
```

Then this in my component typescript file

```
@ViewChild('layout') canvasRef;

//other code here

drawRectangle(file: any): void
{
    let canvas = this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    let source = new Image();
    source.src = this.imgUrl;

    source.onload = () =>
    {
        context.drawImage(source.src,0,0);
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(file.left, file.top, file.width, file.height);
        context.stroke();  
    };


}
```

Comment: ....and what happens?

Comment: @putonspectacles nothing happens

Comment: update your question to reflect what "nothing happens" means. also see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding the `onload()` callback **after** the updating the `source.src`. also you need to pass the image (`source`) to `drawImage` not `source.src` so here is the updated code:

so

```
@ViewChild('layout') canvasRef;

//other code here

drawRectangle(file: any): void
{
    let canvas = this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    let source = new Image();

    source.onload = () =>
    {
        context.drawImage(source, 0, 0);
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(file.left, file.top, file.width, file.height);
        context.stroke();  
    };

    source.src = this.imgUrl;




}
```

Comment: it gives an error of Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

Comment: try the updated code, I replaced source.src, with source in the call to drawImage